Sorting algorithm with "switch" and "rotate"
I'm dealing with a Python HW problem that's got me stumped. I need to sort a list of "marbles" (essentially a range that places each number into its own position) that can be in any order and I don't know what a good algorithm for this is. I'm allowed to switch the first two elements of the list or to rotate the first element to the end of the list (rotating on (1,2,3) will make it (2,3,1)).I can do any number of these operations in any order.
The approach I've gone with is to switch the first two elements if needed to put the larger number in the first position, then rotate that to the end and repeat this logic until sorted. This only works for some lists (such as (1,3,0,2)) but not others (such as (1,3,2,0,4)). The second list results in an infinite loop as it keeps going back to a certain repeating sequence that never progresses.
I've seen this question being asked for this problem before but no answers have gone over the algorithm itself instead of the code layout. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
class MarblesBoard:

    # Initialize a board with a given input sequence (needs to be a consecutive set of integers starting from 0, in any order)
    def __init__(self, sequence):
        self.positions = []
        for marble in sequence:
            self.positions.append(marble)


    # Switch first two element in the board
    def switch(self):
        self.positions[0], self.positions[1] = self.positions[1], self.positions[0]


    # Pop out first marble and move to end of board
    def rotate(self):
        self.positions.append(self.positions.pop(0))

    # Create str and repr output strings
    def __str__(self):
        output = ""
        for marble in self.positions:
            output += (str(marble)+ " ")
        output = output.strip()
        return output

    def __repr__(self):
        output = ""
        for marble in self.positions:
            output += (str(marble)+ " ")
        output = output.strip()
        return output
    
    # Check if every marble is in the correct position (is it solved?)
    def is_solved(self):
        for i in range(len(self.positions)):
            if i != self.positions[i]:
                return False
        return True
    
class Solver:

    # Initialize a game with a previously created MarblesBoard object and a game history
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board
        self.history = [("start", str(self.board))]

    # Solve the game (current algo is switch to get higher of first two elements to position 0, then rotate  to push this to the end)
    def solve(self):
        while not self.board.is_solved():
        
            if self.board.positions[0] < self.board.positions[1]:
                self.board.switch()
                self.history.append(("switch", str(self.board)))

            self.board.rotate()
            self.history.append(("rotate", str(self.board)))


        
        return self.history

# Running the code with a provided test case (this one works)
board = MarblesBoard([1,3,0,2])
solver = Solver(board)
solver.solve()


What you call "switch" is generally called "swap".

Makes sense, "switch" is just the convention required for this assignment.

There's no method for this in your current implementation, but is there any reason that a user of your MarblesBoard class shouldn't be able to learn how many values it contains? E.g. something equivalent to len(board.positions)? WIth that, you could implement bubble sort or any number of other simple sorting algorithms that only need to swap adjacent values. With the length, you know how many rotations are needed to get back to the original position (so you don't accidentally bubble the largest value back to the front of the list).

Your solver accesses .positions - can the solver access any position, or just the first 2? And if it can access any, does that mean it also has access to the length (as Blckknght is asking as well)?

Thinking about the problem, I'm wondering if it's possible to solve it at all without more information. It would probably be helpful if you included the full text of the assignment instead of just describing the problem in your own words, filtered through your understanding. The problem is clear, but it's unclear if you're using all the information available to you.

@Grismar - my answer limits comparisons to just the first 2 elements. It uses an approach similar to merge sort. A prior answer with no limitations on data access or usage of other structures .

@rcgldr your answer doesn't provide code to verify the solution generally though. I wouldn't accept it as an answer if it just provides a description of an idea of an answer. OP should provide a complete problem description though. It's quite possible the answer by "no comment" is much closer to what is needed (one of them at least)

@Grismar - I added the code to my answer.

Bubble sort:
    def solve(self):
        b = self.board
        p = b.positions
        while not b.is_solved():
            for _ in range(len(p) - 1):
                if p[0] > p[1]:
                    b.switch()
                b.rotate()
            b.rotate()

Attempt This Online!
Or with using 0 to determine the one position to not switch:
    def solve(self):
        b = self.board
        p = b.positions
        while not b.is_solved():
            if p[0] > p[1] > 0:
                b.switch()
            b.rotate()

And a version without using the provided is_solved, instead tracking it myself in the typical bubble sort way:
    def solve(self):
        b = self.board
        p = b.positions
        while True:
            switched = False
            for _ in range(len(p) - 1):
                if p[0] > p[1]:
                    b.switch()
                    switched = True
                b.rotate()
            b.rotate()
            if not switched:
                return


Bubble sort to switch adjacent elements is very idiomatic.

These are concise implementations under the assumption that OP either has access to the list length, or that a sentinel can be picked (0, assuming these are positive integers and 0), respectively. That's not a given though.

@Grismar I think they are givens, just not by text but by their code.

@Neil Yeah I usually don't like bubble sort, but here the allowed two operations pretty much imply it. (I guess we could also do a backwards insertion sort, i.e., inserting towards the "back".)

May I please know the reason for the downvote so I can understand the issue and perhaps resolve it?

Not sure, I don't think you could do any better (in O(1) space, at least)—without random access. Most importantly, bubble-sort is likely to most likely the intended assignment solution paradigm.

May I please know the reason for the second downvote so I can understand the issue and perhaps resolve it?

The main problem occurs when position 0 is in its right position, since it will never leave that position again, and you will just keep on rotating the other number to the back of the board. I tried this attempt, which at least could solve the boards you have provided plus some boards I made up myself:
def solve(self):
    while not self.board.is_solved():

        if self.board.positions[0] == len(self.board.positions) - 1:
            self.board.rotate()
            self.history.append(("rotate", str(self.board)))
            continue

        if self.board.positions[0] > self.board.positions[1]:
            self.board.switch()
            self.history.append(("switch", str(self.board)))

        self.board.rotate()
        self.history.append(("rotate", str(self.board)))

I switch the two numbers if the first one is largest. If the largest element of the board is ever placed at the beginning, it will be rotated to the back. I am not sure if this will solve the problem always.

I see, thanks for the heads up! I'll give it a shot and let you know once I'm back at my PC.

This method restricts comparisons to just the first two elements of the array, and does not use any other containers, such as another array. It is similar to a bottom up merge sort. It uses rotate to rotate the entire array, and swap and rotate to rotate all but the first element of the array. Some small optimizations could be done, but point of this answer is proof of concept.
When creating runs, if array size is not a power of 2, the last run will have fewer elements.
Create sorted runs of 2. First run: rotate 0 into first position, rotate 1 into second position to create [0,1]. Second run: rotate 2 into first position, rotate 3 into second position to create [2,3] ...
Create sorted runs of 4. First run: rotate 1 into first position, rotate [2,3] into second position to create [1,2,3]. Rotate 0 into first position, rotate [1,2,3] into second position to create [0,1,2,3]. Second run: rotate 5 into first position, rotate [6,7] into second position to create [5,6,7]. Rotate 4 into first position, rotate [5,6,7] into second position to create [4,5,6,7] ...
Create sorted runs of 8. First run: rotate 3 into first position, rotate [4,5,6,7] into second position to create [3,4,5,6,7]. Rotate 2 into first position, rotate [3,4,5,6,7] into second position to create [2,3,4,5,6,7]. Rotate 1 into first position, rotate [2,3,4,5,6,7] into second position to create [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. Rotate 0 into first position, rotate [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] into second position to create [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ...
    def solve(self):
        l = len(self.board.positions)
        r = 1                               # current run size
        s = 2                               # next run size
        while s < l :
            d = 0
            while True :
                f = d + r
                if f >= l :
                    break
                e = f - 1
                while e >= d :
                    while self.board.positions[0] != e :
                        self.board.rotate()
                    while self.board.positions[1] != f :
                        self.board.switch()
                        self.board.rotate()
                    f = e
                    e = f - 1
                d = d + s
                if d >= l :
                    break
            r = s
            s = s * 2
        while self.board.positions[0] != 0 :
            self.board.rotate()

7 0 6 1 5 2 4 3
0 6 1 5 2 4 3 7  0
0 1 5 2 4 3 7 6  [0,1]
2 4 3 7 6 0 1 5
2 3 7 6 0 1 5 4  [2,3]
4 2 3 7 6 0 1 5
4 5 2 3 7 6 0 1  [4,5]
6 0 1 4 5 2 3 7
6 7 0 1 4 5 2 3  [6,7]
1 4 5 2 3 6 7 0
1 2 3 6 7 0 4 5  [1,2,3]
0 4 5 1 2 3 6 7
0 1 2 3 6 7 4 5  [0,1,2,3]
5 0 1 2 3 6 7 4
5 6 7 4 0 1 2 3  [5,6,7]
4 0 1 2 3 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3  [4,5,6,7]
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  sorted

Had there been more than 8 elements, to create the first group of 8:
4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 x x x x
3 x x x x 4 5 6 7 0 1 2
3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 x x x x
2 x x x x 3 4 5 6 7 0 1
2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 x x x x
1 x x x x 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 x x x x
0 x x x x 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 x x x x


Mergesort seems like a masochistic choice for this :-). Does it have any advantage? What's the "time" complexity (number of operations)?

@nocomment - the only advantage is that it doesn't use is_sorted. If compare is limited to the first two elements, then is_sorted would take n rotates and n-1 compares.

You mean is_solved? That's provided by the MarblesBoard, and it doesn't use rotates. I considered using a fixed number of rounds instead (or I could track whether switches happened in a round) but then just kept the OP's solver's usage of it. Still, any idea about your time complexity? I'm wondering since the supported operations are so extremely inconvenient for mergesort, probably requiring many operations.

@nocomment - Using reversed order data, I got these results: {n,swaps,rotates} = {4,12,16} {8,40,92} {16,272,544} {32,1568,2832} {64,8256,13760} {128,41088,64192} {256,196864,291840} ... . Looks like rotates starts at O(n^{2.5}), and is O(n^{2.12}) at n = 2048.

@nocomment - a prior answer with no limitations .

Might actually be O(n^2). Your inner two loops move e before e+1, and I think the rest of the code just organizes it so that every number from 0 to l-2 becomes e at one point. So I think that's O(n^2). Though maybe not, as the measured numbers are so much larger than n^2. Btw If you replace all that e-organization with just for e in reversed(range(l - 1)):, the rotates for n=256 drop to 65025. Btw better call the variable n instead of l, both for readability and consistency (even you yourself already used the common name n now).

Ah, no, you repeat e-values. So I think it's O(log(n) * n * n) = O(n^2 log n). Then I think the simple for e in reversed(range(l - 1)): is really much better.

Which bubble implementation? Mine take me ~3 seconds for that, while your solution takes me ~19 seconds.

@nocomment - I'm running Python 2.7. I changed is_solved to use xrange instead of range and it now runs in ~ 8 seconds, so 8 versus 37 seconds. I just threw this code together, and I'm not familiar with Python, so the code could be cleaned up. If is_solved had to rotate the entire array, it would be slower, but it's not required for the OP's question.

Ok that explains it. (But opens the new question why you're using Python 2 :-)

@nocomment - I'm running Python 2.7 to run some mod on an old racing game that used to be online only, that allowed it to be run offline, since that old game server was shut down. I rarely use Python, Mostly C, C++, assembly, since that is what I worked with as a programmer (I retired back in 2008).

Ok, for that it makes sense. It's just odd to still see it used, more than four years after it officially died.

@nocomment  -  The game was Need For Speed World. Server was shut down July 2015. The fan made "offline" version 1.7.0 was released in June 2015, (before the shutdown in order to fix any bugs). Around 2019, they made replacement servers, but made content changes over time. The offline server has all of the original content on the player's PC if a player wants to take a trip down memory lane.
